# My Requirement is need to update the oracle table from azure data factory

Tags: oracle, azure, azure-data-factory

> ErrorCode=InvalidParameter,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The
> value of the property 'columns' is invalid: 'Value cannot be null.
> Parameter name:
> columns'.,Source=,''Type=System.ArgumentNullException,Message=Value
> cannot be null. Parameter name:
> columns,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,'

when I used lookup activity I was getting above is the error. please can someone help here with

Query : : -

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEE
  SET JOB=NULL, SALARY=0
  WHERE WORKDEPT = 'E21'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by missing return value from your update.

Against an MSSQL db you could add a line:
SELECT 'Finished'

And you would have a return value.

For Oracle it would be something like:
SELECT 'Finished' FROM DUAL;

But I do not know the exact syntax to do both the update AND the select part against an oracle source from an ADF lookup activity.